# TestRestTemplate.postForEntity changes behavior when adding aws-java-sdk to the project

Tags: aws-sdk, spring-security-oauth2, http-status-code-401, spring-boot-test

I have the following test in my springboot (v1.4.0.RELEASE) project with OAuth authorization.

```
@Test(expected = ResourceAccessException.class)
public void accessWithUnknownClientID() throws IOException {

        ResponseEntity<String> response = new TestRestTemplate("trusted-app", "wrongpass")
                .postForEntity("http://localhost:" + port + "/oauth/token?client_id=trusted-app&grant_type=client_credentials", null, String.class);

}
```

The test works fine until I add the aws-java-sdk in which case instead of throwing the ResourceAccessException the call returns 401 unauthorized.